# Lossless merging of PDFs (PHP)

Tags: php, pdf, merge, imagemagick

Currently I am using [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) to merge multiple PDFs into one in a PHP script on my Linux system. However, the resulting PDFs are of very low quality. I have stumbled across [pdftk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftk) which seems to have a better quality after the merging, but I need to use ImageMagick if possible because I need to get the script to run on another server which does not have pdftk (and it would be a pain to get it on there).

How can I merge PDFs using ImageMagick and PHP with lossless quality?

Answer (score 4):

ImageMagick can't do lossless PDF merging. If you have a Linux server, you may try pdfconcat (which does lossless merging very quickly):

```
$ wget -O pdfconcat http://www.math.bme.hu/~pts/cvsget.cgi/u=bin.i386/p=/M=bin.i386/c=f1/n=/bin.i386/pdfconcat
$ chmod +x pdfconcat
$ ./pdfconcat -o output.pdf input1.pdf input2.pdf input3.pdf
```

Comment: that's pretty cool; definitely going to be adding this to my workstation :)

Answer (score 0):

My [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/) Perl library includes a flexible command-line tool called [appendpdf.pl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?appendpdf.pl) which can mix arbitrary pages of a PDF into another document.