# Merge PDFs and retain their index (xref-Table?)

Tags: pdf, merge, indexing

I want to merge two PDF-files retaining the index (the xref-table) of both files.

I wanted to write my thesis in LaTeX, except for the covering page which is rather fancy and complex. Now I want to merge the covering page of my thesis with the contents, but I could not accomplish this job with retaining the index using the following tools:

- pdftk and the
- tools presented in [Lossless merging of PDFs (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848513/lossless-merging-of-pdfs-php).

The PDF Toolkit (pdftk) provides a "dump_data" command with which it is possible to extract metadata information including the bookmarks. This data can be brought into a pdf-file using the "update_info" command which works, except for the bookmarks.

Can anybody out there give me a tip on how to work that out?

Thanks for helping me, Rainer

Comment: *I want to merge two PDF-files retaining the index (the xref-table) of both files* - assuming you really mean the PDF-internal cross-reference table, your task in general is impossible to implement. But I actually assume you want something else, like keeping bookmarks operational...

Comment: If you just want a fancy cover page, I'd suggest converting the cover page to EPS and ask LaTeX to render that EPS as full page sized for the cover page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a PDF in someway without changing the original Xref table or stream then you will need to save changes to the document as an incremental update. This will result in any changes to the document being made in the update section at the bottom of the file. Here's a diagram visually demonstrating it:

[image]

If you don't use an incremental update then when the PDF is saved it will be re-written and a new Xref table or stream will be created.

You will need to find a library that supports incremental updates.